# Getting image url of message attachment from Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently have the following problem:

I am building a system with which I can handle service requests from Facebook. I get all of the conversations on my page with this request:

```
PAGE_ID/conversations?fields=messages{message, attachments}
```

This returns the following data (for example), when the message is an image:

```
{
        "message": "",
        "attachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "IMAGE_ID",
              "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
              "name": "IMAGE_NAME.jpg",
              "size": null,
              "image_data": {
                "width": 720,
                "height": 960,
                "render_as_sticker": false,
                "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/v/wl/t34.0-12/IMAGE_NAME.jpg?oh=SOME_CHANGING_STRING&oe=SOME_OTHER_CHANGING_STRING",
                "image_type": 1,
                "max_width": 720,
                "max_height": 960
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "id": "MESSAGE_ID"
}, ...
```

I first stored the image url in my own database, but after a day the URLs are changing in the parts indicated in the data above. So my initial plan was to do an additional request to the Graph API like this, to get the new URL:

```
MESSAGE_ID/attachments
```

But the problem is that I can not get the image data with this request, the field 'image_data' is not found. I can not seem to find another way to get the updated image url, other than checking the conversations edge again (which is not ideal due to the latency of this request).

Does anyone have any clue how to get the new image url efficiently?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's is no other way. image_data is only available on the conversations endpoint. However instead of just storing the CDN cache URL why not simply download the attachment and save it on your server? Attachments are very unlikely to change, so that is your only option unless you want to update all conversations again and again just to retrieve a current CDN cache URL.

Side note: You can only get that URL for images btw, but not for other attachments like a PDF for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Storing the image on my server is indeed an option that I can look at. However, I found out that the Message edge can also provide me the image data: `MESSAGE_ID?fields=attachments` instead of `MESSAGE_ID/attachments`. I find this a bit unclear in the documentation.